# Cannot read property 'collection' of undefined while connecting to mongodb in node.js?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I am trying to login from my signin.ejs file,after click on the login button in
  my signin page it shows "Cannot read property collection undefined" what is the 
  problem.

I defined my route like this in app.js:

```
app.post('/login', routes.dologin);
```

I defined my dologin route in index.js:

```
exports.dologin = function (req, res) {
res.locals.session = req.session;

var user = req.body.user;
db.authenticateUser(user.email, user.password, function     ( err, response) {
if (err) {
.......

.......
} else {
.......

........  
}
});
};
```

In my db.js:

```
var mongo = require('mongoskin'),
crypto = require('crypto');

module.exports = function (config) {

var USERS_COLLECTION = 'users',
ORDERS_COLLECTION = 'orders',
salt = 'supersecretkey',
db;

    authenticateUser: function (emailId, password,         callback) {
    db.collection(USERS_COLLECTION).count({email : emailId,         password: encryptPassword(password)}, function (err,         count) {
    if (err) {
console.log("error authenticating user: " + err);
callback(new Error(err));
} else if (count === 0) {
callback(new Error("emailid/password did not match"));
} else {
callback(null);
}
});
},
    }
```

What is the problem here for getting "Collection undefined"? i think here 
  everything is right... Is there any problem here?tell me..please Thanks.

Comment: `db` IS undefined, `var db` isn't a valid DB object

Answer (score 0):

You should add this code `db = mongo.db('localhost:27017/yourdb');`

```
var mongo = require('mongoskin'),
    crypto = require('crypto');

module.exports = function (config) {

    var USERS_COLLECTION = 'users',
        ORDERS_COLLECTION = 'orders',
        salt = 'supersecretkey',
        db = mongo.db('localhost:27017/yourdb');

    authenticateUser: function (emailId, password, callback) {

        db.collection(USERS_COLLECTION).count({
            email: emailId,
            password: encryptPassword(password)
        }, function (err, count) {
            if (err) {
                console.log("error authenticating user: " + err);
                callback(new Error(err));
            } else if (count === 0) {
                callback(new Error("emailid/password did not match"));
            } else {
                callback(null);
            }
        });
    },
}
```

Comment: but i added like this in return statement : 
 return {
  configure: function (config) {
   db = mongo.db((config ? config : 'mongodb://localhost:27017/paypal'), {w : 1});
  }